# Are "What software should I use to..."-questions accepted?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, people want to do something specific in their music that is not their specialty. Like a guitarist who wants to record drums, synth, etc...
For example: "What can I use to record virtual drums?",
"What can I use to make choir for my track?".
Are question about such topics accepted?

Answer (score 3):

In general, we prefer the format "How can I do X?".  If your question is about something that's obviously going to require software, it doesn't make too much of a difference whether you ask directly for software or follow the format above, although the latter may be better received.

What we do want to avoid is poll or popularity questions.  Answers should be complete and tell you how to solve your problem, not be a one-liner with a link to some software.  We also don't want a huge number of answers all pointing to different software.  So your job as an asker is to elicit those more thorough and useful answers.  If you want to do something basic, it's better just to do some research and try something out.  If you're having trouble with particular software or can't easily find something that fits your needs then asking about that here would be great!

Answer (score 2):

I think a question like this would be more fit on the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site; but, if well written, it might fit here as well. Usually recomendations are frowned upon on the SE Q&A Sites (except for the above mentioned site), but there have been exceptions.

Take a look at this meta thread:

- [Defining Music
  Software](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/705/defining-music-software)